# If statement for an autoclicker

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a clicker game, and when the clicks reach a certain number, something happens. Nothing happens. Any ideas as to why the if statement I added isnt doing anything when reaching the number of ten clicks?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clicker</title>
    <script src="counter.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="2hfp1SzUoho7/TsGGGDaFdsuuDL0LX2hnUp6VkX3CUQ2K4K+xjboZdsXyp4oUHZj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-THPy051/pYDQGanwU6poAc/hOdQxjnOEXzbT+OuUAFqNqFjL+4IGLBgCJC3ZOShY" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.2.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-Plbmg8JY28KFelvJVai01l8WyZzrYWG825m+cZ0eDDS1f7d/js6ikvy1+X+guPIB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="VjEeINv9OSwtWFLAtmc4JCtEJXXBub00gtSnszmspDLCtC0I4z4nqz7rEFbIZLLU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            text-align: center;
            background-image: url("https://gift-frog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/off-white-textured-background-1920x10803.jpg");
        }
        h1{
            font-size: 100px;
            color: #372424;
        }
        h3{
            color: #372424;
        }
        h2{
            color: #372424;
        }
        *.unselectable {
            -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;

            /*
              Introduced in IE 10.
              See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
            */
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body id="body" onclick="doClick()">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    &#9776;
  </button>
  <div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
    <div class="bg-inverse p-a-1">
      <h4>Your Statistics</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">graph in development</span>
        <br>
        <h4>Rank</h4>
        <progress class="progress progress-success" value="bob" max="500"></progress>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h1 class="unselectable">Clicked <h1 class="unselectable" id="counter">0</h1></h1> <h1 class="unselectable">times</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript for it.

```
    /**
 * Created by Illuminati on 9/8/2016.
 */
var clicks = 0;
var multiplyer = 0;

function doClick() {
    clicks = clicks + 1;
    var theCounter = document.getElementById('counter');
    theCounter.textContent = clicks;
}
if(clicks == 10){
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: Move the conditional to inside the function. Outside of it, it's only being read on page load where it is always false.

Comment: Do you think I should make an interval to constantly do a check? Or do you thinking leaving it in the click function is smarter because it will just check as soon as they click.

Comment: @KodySimpson Don't place it inside an a interval. If the only time `click` changes is inside the function there is no need for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the conditional to inside the function. Outside of it, it's only being read on page load where it is always false.

Comment: Thank you, quick question about an autoclicker if you wouldnt mind helping me... Im trying to make it do a click every 5 seconds with this: window.setInterval(function () {
        if (rank1 != true){
            return false;
        }
        doClick();
    }, 5000)
} but instead it does as many clicks as it can during 5 seconds and no clicks obviously during 5 seconds after that

Comment: Aside from the extra } at the end, that seems like it should work. setInterval waits until the first interval has been reached to fire the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` block you have only ever runs once, but your event handler runs whenever the user click on the button.

Something like this:

```
function doClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    var theCounter = document.getElementById('counter');
    theCounter.textContent = clicks;
    if(clicks == 10){
      alert("test");
    }
}
```

Also instead of doing, `counter = counter + 1` you could also use, `clicks += 1` which is the exact same thing.